# Mongodb license for an e-commerce website?

Tags: mongodb

Do you have to pay a mongodb license for an e-commerce website?

Can I use the free license?

Comment: Did you do any web searching at ALL before asking this question?   https://www.mongodb.com/pricing

Comment: Yes. On your link there is nowhere written that I can use a free license for an e-commerce website.

Comment: MongoDB community edition is free to do whatever you want commercial or not, as far as i know. [Read this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432037/mongodb-for-commercial-use) and [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/can-we-use-mongo-community-edition-for-free-of-cost-in-production-environment/10656/2)

Comment: This question is asking for legal advice, which is definitely off-topic for stackoverflow.  My advice is to read the license that came with the software, and then consult a lawyer familiar with the laws in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongo free license is based on GPL. Software under the GPL may be run for all purposes, including commercial purposes and even as a tool for creating proprietary software.

The main difference between GPL and the "customized" SSPL license from MongoDB is: You may not offer MongoDB yourself as a **paid** cloud service.

The reason is simple: With MongoDB Atlas Cloud service they like to run this kind of business solely.