# Is MongoDB Community Edition allow for Commercial Purposes?

Tags: mongodb

I'm fresh graduate student. My friend and I plan to install the MongoDB Community Edition in customer site, then use a python script to process a json file produced by customer machine. Then use the platform called VONE, MongoDB direct connection (new feature in V-One haven't release yet) to query the data and plot into V-One DA. Is it legal for us to use MongoDB Community Edition for the following purposes? Please advise me whether it is legal to use MongoDB Community Edition for the following purposes.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432037/mongodb-for-commercial-use) question.

Comment: In general you can do everything with the Community Edition - apart from selling Mongo database as a cloud service. This service is solely admitted to MongoDB Atlas.